# android layout causes crash on actionbar addtab

Tags: android

I am having a terrible time trying to figure out the problem in my Andriod app. The
code was running fine and then I updated to Andriod Studio 0.2.9 and also made some
changes and am now stuck.

I have the following layout for the activity, where I cut out some of the lower
level items for brevity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ViewActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_view"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_view_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        ... content omitted ...

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            >
        ... content omitted ...


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_view_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            >
        ... content omitted ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_view_data"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_view_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="@drawable/level_divider"
        android:dividerPadding="20dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_levels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" >

        ... content omitted ...

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_View"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:longClickable="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that whenever I include the +id/listView_View item, I get a crash
when trying to add a tab in the oncreate method. The layout looks fine the previewer,
which doesn't show errors either.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mDefault_drawable = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_item_question );
    mHeader_drawable = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_header_icon );

    // define defaults
    index_in_modc = -1;
    mView_layout = ViewLayout.VL_DATA;
    view_style = 0;

    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_view_view).setText(R.string.view_view).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_view_tags).setText(R.string.view_manage_tags).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home).setText(R.string.main_home).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_help).setText(R.string.help).setTabListener(this));
             ...
```

If I remove the +id/listView_View item then the code seems to work and I get no crashes. I have tried
all types of rebuilds, commenting out various things, etc. I am suspcious of errors due to 0.2.9 update,
or maybe library mismatches but after many days I just can't figure it out. Any help or suggestions
are more than welcome!

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to try:

1) Only use lowercase ids (not sure if there's an actual precidence/best practices for this, I just think it looks better :) Try it anyway and see if it helps.

2) Try renaming it to something else, like "@+id/lv_main".

3) Try cleaning your project.

4) It looks like your XML is malformed. Is there something missing?

5) is there more code that's relevant to the listview?  Like an adapter or something?

6) what's the exception stacktrace?

Comment: I was following a red-herring. The issue was that upon creation of the first tab the tabselected code runs. I had moved some class initialization from OnCreate to OnResume and had a null exception.